Converting currencies to USD in as calculated field in Workday
I am trying to convert all amount in different currencies aside to all amount in USD. I selected Total base pay - amount as the source field, USD as the target code, selected to add currency code, etc. CF was created but the column in my report remained unconverted even if I added the CF
I tried to do T/F CF first then created the conversion and applied both to an Evaluate Expression CF but it did not work.

it's unclear why you've elected to incorporate a T/F or Eval Expression field. You should be able to create a calculated field of type "Convert Currency".
Did you check to make sure that you have the conversion rate you are looking for as of the date specified in your calculated field? Spend some time exploring the task "Maintain Currency Conversion Rates" to double check that a rate exists.
